# console input into arraylist java without duplicate input

Tags: java

Task:  write a Java program that will allow a user of the program to assign only one runner to each of the 8 lanes of running track in a field.

I am able to get the input process, array list, setters and getters to work correctly but my problem is I am stumped on how to limit the input number of 8 lanes to where only one lane per runner may be assigned.  Here is my input code currently:

```
public List<Item> createListOfCompetitors(){

    List<Item> newListOfCompetitors = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Competing Runner Name");
            String name = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Assign a lane to the runner! ");
            while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Use a valid number");
                sc.next();
            }
            double lane = sc.nextDouble();
            Item item = new Item(name, lane);
            newListOfCompetitors.add(item);
            System.out.println("Enter Y to continue or N to quit");
            sc.nextLine();
        } while (sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
    return newListOfCompetitors;
}
```

[Dependencies in my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mp17.png)

Comment: How about using an array (index = lane number) or a map (key = lane number)?

Comment: use a Map with key as lane number and value as runner name?

Comment: I know that could work but I do not understand how I can implement a limit  for the console input to say where when I assign a runner name to a track lane so that it gives an error if I try to assign the second , third ,fourth runner name to an already assigned lane.  Does that make more sense?  The only thing I need to do is figure out how to only allow use of an unused track lane number during input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might go for using a map of lanes to items to represent the lanes which are occupied.  This way, you can add a condition which checks if the lane entered from the console already be occupied or not.

```
public Map<Double, Item> createListOfCompetitors() {
    Map<Double, Item> lanes = new HashMap<>();

    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter Competing Runner Name");
            String name = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Assign a lane to the runner! ");
            double lane;
            do {
                String lane = sc.nextLine();
                try {
                    lane = Double.parseDouble(lane);
                    if (lanes.get(lane) == null) {
                        lanes.put(lane, new Item(name, lane));
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Lane number already chosen.");
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid lane number.");
                }
           } while (true);
       } while (sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
   }

    return lanes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that will answer my problem.  Now off to learn more about maps!  Thanks again!